# Why is boolean the only type for which there are no coercions or casts defined?

Tags: java, language-design

It seems reasonable to not allow

```
int a = 8;
boolean b = (boolean)a;
```

because that could lead to programmer errors, because the resulting boolean would be false for even integers, but why doesn't a widening coercion, e.g. `int a = true` work?

**Edit:**

According to the JVM specification, Section 3.3.4:

> The Java virtual machine encodes boolean array components using 1 to
>   represent true and 0 to represent false. Where Java programming
>   language boolean values are mapped by compilers to values of Java
>   virtual machine type int, the compilers must use the same encoding.

For example:

```
public static boolean returnFalse() {
    return false;
}

public static boolean returnTrue() {
    return true;
}
```

compiles to:

```
public static boolean returnFalse();
  Code:
     0: iconst_0
     1: ireturn

public static boolean returnTrue();
  Code:
     0: iconst_1
     1: ireturn
```

Comment: What would be the value of a? And why? Is 1 more true than 23, -567 or 0?

Comment: Because an int isn't a boolean. I don't quite get the "odd integers" thing.

Comment: Clearly 42 is more true than -567.

Comment: anyway select the most useful answer as best answer, dear Rose

Comment: @DaveNewton, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I realized after I was done typing it it seemed more answery than commenty :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The internal representation isn't relevant.

Java is strongly-typed: an `int` isn't a `boolean`, and a `boolean` isn't an `int`.

This was a design decision--if you want to use true/false, use booleans; that communicates something.

If you want to use an integer to *represent* true/false, use mathematical comparisons--that's fine too.

The language doesn't support direct conversion because it doesn't, by design.

---

Regarding the JVM spec and the internal representation of booleans, this sentence is interesting:

> Where Java programming language boolean values are mapped by compilers to values of Java virtual machine type int, the compilers must use the same encoding.

To me, that reads:

> *If* the compiler/VM is using a VM integer to represent true/false, *then* it must use the 1/0 convention. *With the implication being:* If the compiler/VM *isn't* using a VM integer for true/false, this isn't a requirement.

Clarification on this point would be interesting, but ultimately not related, really.

Comment: I guess you should add a viceversa in the "an int isn't a boolean" part :).

Comment: Why is `float f = 3` legal? Aren't widening coercions legal for other data types?

Comment: @RosePerrone Not *arbitrary* data types; both ints and floats are numeric. A boolean *does not represent a number*: it represents true, or false, and that is all.

Comment: @RosePerrone an integer value is a real value :).

Answer (score 0):

Java is not C++ to hold one 0 for false and 1 for true. In java boolean is a different data type. C++ need at least 1 byte to have a boolean. In java it depends on the JVM implementation.

Comment: (ie) to say true or false 1 bit is enough, no need to have 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convention that in languages such as C++ 0 is false and all other integers are true. Java doesn't have any convention specifying a boolean value to any integers.

I'm confused by "why doesn't a widening coercion, e.g. int a = true work" are you wondering why they didn't make it so this would assign 1 to a?

Comment: Correct. The JVM specification indicates that the internal representation is a single bit, so I would assume the integer representation of a boolean would be 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh I see, ya you've got a point. Just because that's the way it actually works (as in that's how it's stored in the virtual machine) they made it so you can't do that with the source code.

Comment: It comes down to that they made the compiler not allow that.